# ColorBox with gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery, settings, colorbox

I have a little gallery:

- Big photo
- Little thumbs at the bottom

When a user click on a thumb the big photo change, oke great.

Now i have add the Colorbox plugin on the big photo so when a user click on the big photo he see a bigger one, that works. But when a user first click on some thumbs and then they click on the big photo ColorBox loads but dont load the settings that i have add.

**Here is my js**:

```
$(function() {
$("#wrapper #right #detail #photo #big #image a").colorbox({
    transition: 'elastic',
    speed: 200,
    opacity: 0.4,
    scalePhotos : true,
    maxWidth : '800px'
});

$("#wrapper #right #detail #photo ul li .thumb").click(function() {
    var image = $(this).attr("rel");
    $('#image').hide();
    $('#image').fadeIn('fast');
    $('#image').html('<a href="' + image + '" class="cboxElement" title=""><img src="' + image + '" alt="" /></a>');
    return false;
});
});
```

**And the HTML**:

```
<div id="photo">
<div id="big"><div id="image"><a href="gfx/detail/1.jpg"><img src="gfx/detail/1.jpg" border="0"/></a></div></div>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#" rel="gfx/detail/1.jpg" class="thumb"><img src="gfx/detail/1.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="gfx/detail/2.jpg" class="thumb"><img src="gfx/detail/2.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="gfx/detail/3.jpg" class="thumb"><img src="gfx/detail/3.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Can somewone help me so that colorbox loads the settings?

Comment: can you share complete code? So that i can see whats wrong with it

Comment: I have add the HTML...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#wrapper #right #detail #photo #big #image a")
$("#wrapper #right #detail #photo ul li .thumb")
```

No need in such long selectors, you lose performance. `#` is id selector and id must be unique, that why you can remove `#wrapper #right #detail`

You replacing element on which attach colorbox options, problems lies on this level, as solution you can bind `click`. Like this:

```
$('#image').on('click', 'a', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.colorbox({
       transition: 'elastic',
       href: this.href,
       speed: 200,
       opacity: 0.4,
       scalePhotos : true,
       maxWidth : '800px'
   });
});
```

Comment: Hi webdeveloper, i get the same result that the settings from colorbox don't load when i first click some thumbs...